# xamarin for visual studio not showing simulator list

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm pretty new to xamarin, tried to run a sample application (IOS). But  Visual Studio says: `"Please select a valid device before running the application"`

I know on the IOS toolbar, there should be option to select which device to simulate (list of supported IOS devices like iphone 6, 5s etc), but I don't get that.

EDIT: To be more precise,  TARGET IOS Device not shown on IOS Tool bar

Comment: Do you own a Mac? Is it connected to your Windows machine via the Build Host?

Comment: It is connected to a Mac machine via the build host

Comment: login to the mac and launch XCode.  Be sure it doesn't prompt you about installing any additional software, or needing you to accept a license agreement.

Comment: @Jason I did, and it didn't prompt me anything

Comment: @Jason I had to open a sample application and run. It worked since then. Thank you for your support!

Comment: For me, opening XCode and creating the test project worked. (Open the preview mode which runs Simulator for the first time)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem a year back - please check the following:

- XCode is installed
- you have started XCode once (to accept license agreement)
- Xamarin Build Host is installed
- Visual Studio and Mac Build Host are connected
- Simulators work on MAC-side when started with XCode (just use a sample project)
- Check that you are using latest versions of Xamarin (often, there are major bugs in intermediate versions of Xamarin that are updated relatively quickly), also check that they are compatible with your XCode version and that VS and Mac versions are compatible (only certain versions can cooperate)
- using non-latest versions on Mac side can help (e. g. new XCode releases often are unsupported for a few days till there is an update on Xamarin side)
- Make sure that iOS project is selected for start
- Sometimes, you need to re-establish connection with Build host for things to work properly
- Sometimes, you need to restart your systems
- You got correct licenses (you need Business or Enterprise on both Windows and Mac)

I think for me it was outdated versions and a hickup in the software, after a reboot it worked.

Comment: Ohh yen this works! I Have been told earlier by Jason to open XCode once and they try. But that didn't fix. But now I opened XCode and ran a sample test project on XCode. This does the trick. Since then I could get the simulator. Thank you so much for the support. Have been struggling hard for some days due to this.

Comment: I add this: dev account configured on XCode>Preferences>Accounts

Answer (score 9):

1. Quit Visual Studio.
2. Open your XCode.
3. Restart Visual Studio.
4. Select your ios app > Debug > "Now you can see list of simulators"
5. Quit Xcode.

OR If above steps do not work then try adding new build configuration as shown in following image by selecting iphoneSimulator.

[image]

Comment: I found I could shorten this by only doing step 3 

:P

Comment: @sleeke You got a better luck then. :P

Answer (score 4):

Once in a while I always used to have this issue and solves it by starting Xcode first and then opening VS after. But recently it became consistent after Xcode 12.5 update. So as a trial, I uninstalled VS and reinstalled and now this workaround also stopped working. It's very annoying and there is a bug already reported to Microsoft to fix this.

The solution that worked for me is to

1. Create a multi platform sample project in VS, and viola! I could see all my simulators in my sample project.
2. Now, close this solution (no need to close VS) and open your solution. All your simulators are back.

Unfortunately, you always have to open your sample sln first (but no need to create new sln every time) whenever you want to open your solution. But it solves the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I did everything suggested from other answers, but the only thing that did the trick was to create a new sample project & switching to the actual project.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest XCode version, be sure it's compatible with your Xamarin.iOS and Visual Studio. For me, XCode 13 came out a few days ago and wasn't compatible with the latest Visual Studio. You can download an older version of XCode at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, just be sure to change visual studio to point to the downgraded version in Visual Studio > Preferences > SDK Locations > Apple

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. However, I was able to resolve it by going to XCode>Preferences>Accounts>ViewDetails>Download all. This caused visual studio to now display my device IOS name in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause: Mistakes in editing your iOS platform project's info.plist can cause this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This has started helping me out a lot with VS for Mac when all other options have failed!

- Quit VS for Mac
- Run this in your terminal: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
- Reopen solution in VS for Mac, and you should be able to see the option

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I needed to log into my Apple developer account in XCode again. For some reason it was showing an error state in XCode>Preferences>Account

I logged into my account again then clicked the "download manual" button and now the devices show up in VS.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that the device is connected to the right machine? When I have a VM open on my iMac, I get prompted for which machine I want to connect a device to.

Also make sure that you have `Debug` and `iPhone Simulator` selected.

Comment: Yes I am, also on Debug/IPhone Simulator mode.

Comment: as i cant add images to post see my post on xamarin forum. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52550/xamarin-for-visual-studio-not-showing-simulator-list#latest   I am not getting the option to select at all.