# iOS devices not shown after successfully connecting to MAC agent

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am facing strange issue. The xamarin iOS project connects without any error to the MAC agent but the list of iphone is coming empty. Also in the iOS project properties under `iOS Build` tab shows `Requested value 'key' was not found.`
[image]

Comment: Is you device connected to mac as well?

Comment: Yes the device is connected and also there are 2 simulators which are also no shown

Comment: Please check all the points mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32915909/437146). Plus try to run a sample project.

Comment: _Have you tried turning it off and on again?_